# Execute Dart on Node Js

Tags: dart

Is it possible to develop for node js using compiled javascript from Dart?

I would like to use Node's native APIs in my Dart program. I would like to import and interact with packages installed via NPM. I would like to compile Dart to javascript and execute the code inside node js.

I've looked at the packages node_interop and the build_node_compilers, but these seem to be deprecated (Apr 2022).

I've looked at the grinder and the cli_pkg but this is only for compiling a dart application to javascript without dependencies from the node/js ecosystem, I think.